# Can I programmatically parametrize return value of a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on some functional tests for my application. Depending on the logged user's permissions, the sidebar will have different links. I am parameterizing them (hard coded) and running a test that works well (app is a webtest app):

```
endpoints = [
'/',
'/endpoint1', 
'endpoint2',
...
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('endpoint', endpoints)
def test_endpoints(endpoint, app):
  res = app.get(endpoint).maybe_follow()
  assert res.status_code == 200
```

I would like to avoid having to hard code the list of links for each type of user. Inside a fixture I can actually get them programmatically, so ideally I would like to parametrize the return value of this fixture in order to run the test function above:

```
@pytest.fixture
def endpoints(app):
    res = app.get('/login').follow()
    sidebar_links = []
    for link in res.html.ul.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href') and not link['href'].startswith('#'):
            sidebar_links.append(link['href'])

    return sidebar_links
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use a `for endpoint in endpoints:`?

Comment: This kind of looping is unnecessary here, I am parametrizing the endpoints, so PyTest takes care of running the test for each endpoint. The question is more about if it is possible to parametrize the return value of the endpoints fixture *instead* of using the list that I declare in the first block.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the pytest_configure() hook instead as this method will run before all your test methods. in conftest.py file you can keep a global variable as pytest.endpoints= [] then later in the hook method keep on appending the value of endpoints to this variable
something like this

```
pytest.endpoints= []

def pytest_configure(config,app):

    res = app.get('/login').follow()

    for link in res.html.ul.find_all('a'):
        if link.has_attr('href') and not link['href'].startswith('#'):
            pytest.endpoints.append(link['href'])
```

within the test method use the same variable as a parameter like below

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint",pytest.endpoints)
def test_endpoints(endpoint):
```

Well i am not completely aware of your design so i cannot suggest any further but you can give this a try.

Comment: I tried it, but it won't work because the WebTest app is actually coming from a fixture, so it doesn't exist when the hook runs. I think what I'm trying to achieve is not actually possible with the setup I have